# Setting the Line Height/ Line Spacing in an NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, alignment, nstextview

How would I set the Line Height or Line Spacing in an `NSTextView` (i.e. how tall each line is, or how much space is between each line)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `- (void)setDefaultParagraphStyle:(NSParagraphStyle *)paragraphStyle` method in your NSTextView.

Documentation on [NSParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle?language=objc)

Documentation on [NSMutableParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle?language=objc)

There is a `setLineSpacing:` method in NSMutableParagraphStyle. There are also methods relating to line height, the methods under "Setting Other Style Information" in the NSMutableParagraphStyle documentation should prove useful.

I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: How do I change the NSParagraphStyle to NSMutableParagraphStyle so the setLineSpacing: method will work as this is what I have now (in a NSTextView subclass)  http://grab.by/1ppb. And I get that warning for that problem.

Comment: Change the (NSParagraphStyle *) to (NSMutableParagraphStyle *)

Comment: Thanks, I've just down that but it doesn't actually change the line spacing, any idea why?

Comment: These links are now dead.

Answer (score 21):

leave the answer in case someone need:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle * myStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[myStyle setLineSpacing:10.0];
[myTextView setDefaultParagraphStyle:myStyle];
```

Comment: +1 from me also. If Apple's documentation was genuinely helpful, Stackoverflow's Xcode developer community would be much smaller!