# add space between lines in UITextview ios5

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I am breaking my head to the add more space between lines. If someone tells what need to be done, it will be really helpful.

Using **NSMutableParagraphStyle** this issue can fixed but deployment target is ios5.So NSMutableParagraphStyle is not supported.

**Font size: 18
line gap   30**

code:

CustomNote.h

```
@interface CustomNote : UITextView<UIScrollViewDelegate,
    UITextViewDelegate>{ } @end
```

CustomNote.m

@implementation CustomNote

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
            self.delegate = self;
        }
        return self;
    }



-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor);

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

  CGContextBeginPath(context);

 //NSUInteger numberOfLines = (self.contentSize.height + self.bounds.size.height) / self.font.leading;

  NSUInteger numberOfLines = (self.contentSize.height + self.bounds.size.height) / KLineGap;

  CGFloat baselineOffset = 6.0f;

   for (NSUInteger x = 1; x < numberOfLines; x++) {

                //0.5f offset lines up line with pixel boundary
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x+10, KLineGap *x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width-10, KLineGap *x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
            }

  CGContextClosePath(context);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
        }
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: @AnoopVaidya This while create a problem while retrieving text right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview

Comment: I need to try this.. Thanks

Comment: Hope this is Helps you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958176/setting-the-line-height-line-spacing-in-an-nstextview