# Overriding UITextView styleString will be rejected by Apple

Tags: iphone, uitextview

This was my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810263/add-space-between-lines-in-uitextview-ios5#comment22486111_15810263) related to **how to Set line Height of UITextView for IOS5**. After a lot of searching I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview) and this was useful for fixing the issue.

Will Apple reject my app if I use  **styleString** method.

Answer (score 1):

I know some Apps have not been rejected using this, so I would just try it. As far as I know, it's not a private API so it should be ok!

Comment: did you ever try it, and if so, was your app approved?